# how to add onclick attribute to button beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

```html
<div id="img"></div>
```

I am trying to add a button with onclick to the div using bs4

```
tag = bs4.Tag(soup, name="button", attrs={"onclick"="foo()"})
div = soup.find(id='img')
div.insert(0,tag)
```

Output:

```html
<div id="img">
<button onclick="foo()">
</button>
</div>
```

How can I add `<button onclick=foo()></button>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `<button>` tag with `BeautifulSoup(...)` instead of `bs4.Tag()`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div id="img"></div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

btn = BeautifulSoup('<button onclick="foo()></button>', 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('div#img').append(btn)
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<div id="img"><button onclick="foo()"></button></div>
```